# Connection to RS485 device via ethernet converter

Tags: java, protocols, converters, ethernet, rs485

I have device (electric meter) with unspecified protocol with RS-485. I have some documentation about what messages I can send to get some readings. Goal is to write some Java app to get readings via RS-485 <=> Ethernet converter.
For example here is message should be sent via RS-485 to get current energy spent (written in documentation included with electric meter):

> 01 00 01 08 0 255

In short: How can I send this message to device using converter ?

Which Java lib shoud I use? Would be this message be different if I send it via Ethernet? How do I work with encapsulated Modbus messages in this case? Is there any simple ethernet terminal for Windows 10 to perfofm testing (something like this one for serial port ["Serial Port Monitor"](https://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/)?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 1):

There are COM servers that can do what you need. A converter usually comes with a driver that provides a virtual serial port, so you don't need to handle it inside the application.

However, it usually also provides an API (on top of TCP or UDP) you can use instead of the virtual serial port - this API is most often proprietary and you need to write the code for each COM server type you want to support.